# SqlDataReader Item property loses connection

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, database-connection, sqldatareader

I have this large SQL Server query (legacy) over several tables, that I read with a `SqlDataReader`. It usually has a limited number of rows to handle, but recently I had to use it over a larger number.

After a number of iterations, the `SqlDataReader` object, on reading an `Item()` property, throws a `SqlException` with the code 0x80131904 and the message "Une erreur de niveau transport s'est produite lors de la réception des résultats du serveur. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - Une connexion existante a dû être fermée par l’hôte distant.)" (More details below.)

The message is in my native French and I'm not entirely sure what the official english version is. My translation would be, after some Web searching, "A transport-level error happened on receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)"

I tried it again: the exception was thrown at the exact same row, reading the exact same field. (Subsequent tries showed the exception might be thrown in different places, but that did not vary wildly : out of eight tries, the exception was thrown in only three different places.

The `SqlDataReader` object happily reads that same field on the previous `Read` iterations, and checking the query's results in the database shows that the row where the exception is thrown doesn't have a particular value.

I tried tweaking the query's `Where` clause to get to the exception faster: it actually read more rows than before, then threw the same exception on a different row. (But again, that was more or less on the same row each time with the tweaked query.)

Looking closer, I put a conditional breakpoint on the instruction that throws the exception. It turns out that:

- Reading the `Item()` property with the QuickWatch throws the same exception.
- Reading the `Item()` property for another field that hasn't been read yet in the current iteration throws the same exception.
- Conversely, reading the `Item()` property for other fields already read in the current iteration throws no exception.

I looked up the `SqlDataReader`'s properties before and after the exception. `State` changes, going from `Open` to `Closed` (which is consistent with the exception). `ClientConnectionId` changes as well, its new value being an unsurprising series of `0`s.

What is happening, and how can I prevent that?

**APPENDIX 1**

The code that opens the SqlDataReader is as follows:

```
    Dim z_dreLecteur As IDataReader = Nothing
    Dim z_dcdCommande As IDbCommand = Nothing

[...]

    If TypeOf p_dcxConnexion Is SqlConnection Then
        z_dcdCommande = New SqlCommand(p_strQuery, DirectCast(p_dcxConnexion, SqlConnection))
        Exit Try
    End If

[...]

    z_dcdCommande.CommandTimeout = 600
[...]
    z_dreLecteur = z_dcdCommande.ExecuteReader()
[...]
    z_dcdCommande.Dispose()
```

`p_dcxConnexion` is a parameter, already set before the above code runs.

**APPENDIX 2**
More details on the `SqlException`. 
It has an `InnerException`:

- type `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception`,
- `ErrorCode` -2147467259,
- `Message` "Une connexion existante a dû être fermée par l’hôte distant" ("An existing connexion was forcibly closed by the remote host"),
- `NativeErrorCode` 10054.

The `SqlException` has:

- `ErrorCode` -2146232060,
- `Number` 10054,
- `Message` "Une erreur de niveau transport s'est produite lors de la réception des résultats du serveur. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - Une connexion existante a dû être fermée par l’hôte distant.)", which probably translates to "A transport-level error happened on receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)"

I can add the `StackTrace` if needed, but it's really bulky so I won't for now.

Comment: Does the program use only one SqlConnection throughout (bad), or does it create an SqlConnection, do the operation, and immediately dispose of the SqlConnection (the correct way)?

Comment: The `SqlConnection` used serves solely for the `SqlDataReader`, so it remains open throughout (else the `SqlDataReader` can't read data, right?). But again, it isn't used for any other query.

Comment: At [TCP Provider: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/24e38968-a273-4574-aebd-4b7e1807d237/tcp-provider-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host-source-mssqlserver?forum=sqlreplication) I found this possible reason: "The Database Property under Options "Auto Close" was set to True allowing the server to close "inactive" connections. This must be set to False." There's how to disable it at [Blitz Result: Auto Close Enabled](https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/auto-close-enabled/).

Comment: A very interesting suggestion! Unfortunately, I just checked that and it has already been done. I'll keep looking.

Comment: [Reasons](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b9090abf-bbf6-42df-83f5-d608ba8f8d19/) could be - 1.) The server has been restarted, this will close the existing connections. 2.) Someone or something has killed the SPID that is being used.3.) There is a failover (in a mirror setup for example) again, take a look in the SQL Server log.If there is a failover, try to correlate this timestamp with the time of exception. 4.)This may also be caused by other, non SQL Server related, reasons.

Comment: 1) and 2) don't seem to apply here. 3) sounds unlikely in my context, but I've asked for access to the log. (I don't have access to it readily.) At the very least, it might help.

Comment: @JulieXu-MSFT: our admin guy looked into the log around the time of one crash and saw nothing untoward. Your reason 4) seems to be the most likely.

Comment: @AndrewMorton: by the way, there are instructions in the `Read` loop that open and close another connection to the same base with another `SqlDataReader`, like once every four iterations. I encapsulated them into a `Using` block on the Connection object. The loop lasted four times as long before crashing, still in the same way. Interestingly enough, removing fields from the main query's `Select` clause (turns out they weren't useful) also seems to prolong slightly the loop's lifespan.

Comment: @Jean-DavidLanz Does that other SqlDataReader use a second instance of a connection? I don't think it would work at all if it didn't, but it's best to make that clear.

Comment: @AndrewMorton: Indeed: same connection string, different `SqlConnection` object. Still, I found that commenting them out made the loop go even longer, and then I found a way to incorporate them into the main query. That time, the process went to its natural end without mishap! I happily patted myself on the back and tried it again, for certainty: it crashed again. Very late in the process, but it did.

Comment: @AndrewMorton: tl;dr: second instance indeed, but now I don't even use the secondary queries.

Comment: @Jean-DavidLanz Just how long does it take for it to give the error? Do you get the same problem in SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: @AndrewMorton: The duration is variable. As I said, it's more a question of the process reaching a certain point where using the `Item` property throws a `SqlException` that the connection is closed. (Never mind that the connection was fine a few seconds ago, with nothing to close it.) I tried setting up a conditional breakpoint a few lines of code before the point where the exception usually gets thrown, waiting like five minutes and proceeding step-by-step afterwards... and despite the longer timespan, the exception was thrown from the same `Item` as before.

Comment: @AndrewMorton: The same query in SQL Server Management Studio takes from thirty to ninety seconds to run, but it dutifully yields its 80,000+ rows without further ado.

Comment: @Jean-DavidLanz Is there some processing going on in the program which causes it to take so much longer than the SSMS result? If so, could you read in the data and then process it?

Comment: Oh yes, there is some processing in the program. To summarize exceedingly, it takes the data from that query and, according to a number of criteria I won't bore you with, populates tables in one of two different other databases. Each of the three databases has structures and data that differ a lot from the other two, so it's a lot of processing.

Comment: Indeed, three possibilities I'm envisioning are 1) creating a data object with each `Read` from the main query's `SqlDataReader`, and then using that object in the rest of the loop, 2) chucking the `SqlDataReader` away outright and using a `SqlDataAdapter` instead, 3) cutting my main query in *x* queries, each returning a limited number of rows so that the `SqlDataReader` doesn't get too tired. The latter two would be workarounds and don't explain why the connection gets closed so strangely.

Comment: @Jean-DavidLanz Another thing you might be able to try is to have SQL Server on your machine, to eliminate the possibility of network problems (e.g. slightly faulty Ethernet lead).

Comment: @AndrewMorton interesting possibility but no can do: the application I'm working on will be accessing the database remotely, so I have to process network problems. Besides, I think a faulty Ethernet lead would create random errors, wouldn't it? As I said, this error pops up almost at the same point in the code every time. (The exact point changes when I modify the code, of course, but remains the same after that.) Thanks for putting so much time and effort into this.